# Is there any way to parse XML with "&" or "<" or ">" in the data in R

Tags: xml, r

I have some data in XML files and I'm getting a "`Error: 1: xmlParseEntityRef: no name`". I've narrowed it down to some XML files having "&" or "<" or ">" in the data. For example, there is one where the xml is:

```
...<instruc>count the number of words & letters</instruc>...
...<instruc>if the number of letters per word > 6</instruc>...
```

I've been using the XML package and `xmlParse`. Is there any way I can read in this file and treat the 'bad' characters as just text?

Thanks!

Comment: One way to handle this is to `gsub` them, replacing with their html equivalent.  This may be hard to write a proper regex to handle them.

Comment: Good idea. How can I gsub a "<" without" changing all the tags?

Comment: Well that depends on your data haha.  I'm not a regex expert.

Comment: I suggest asking that as a new question.  Some proper regex people can help you out.

Comment: This really isn't valid XML. Do you have no control over how it's generated? It's always best to try to work with clean data if possible.

Comment: I had no control over it, sadly. You can choose your friends but not what you inherit.

Comment: @iShouldUseAName -- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @mnel I'm not suggesting parsing an XML document with regex.

Comment: Please don't call it XML when it isn't. You'll only confuse people. You don't have some XML files, you have some non-XML files that you want to turn into XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Duncan Lang, the author of the XML package:

1) Use `xmlParseDoc()`. This will parse the XML and remove the 'bad' characters.

2) Use `htmlParse()`. The resulting document will contain the `&amp;` corresponding to the offending `&`
but the document will also have a `<html>` and `<body>` node and the real document
will be the child of the `<body>` node.

This requires no changing of symbols but doesn't preclude the update of the xml file through a `gsub()` on the file read as plain text.